# Fabric-node-js enroll does not create the folder structure for msp

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am using fabric node, When i enroll with admin user using node,Fabric ca create the wallet folder under that its create the private_key and public_key with JSON file which includes the signed identity.

When i use the fabric-ca-client below cmd to enroll the admin, its create the folder structure inside the MSP folder.

```
./bin/fabric-ca-client enroll -d -u http://tls-ca-admin:tls-ca-adminpw@0.0.0.0:7052
```

How i can achieve the same folder structure using the fabric node  enroll.Please suggest me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@fama

Please Note that cryptogen and fabric-CA are tools msp structure is pre programmed

- Nodejs sdk
- gosdk
- java sdk

These are Sdk’s you have to create msp structure of an entity for this you need to understand what exactly present inside the msp folder and accordingly arrange

Comment: thank you for replay, Is their any demo related to it any document related to it, will be helpful

Comment: I don't have any tutorial but this will help you please see my answer in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46465298/understanding-various-certificates-in-hyperledger-fabric/57512792#57512792